# In Pyqt5, QWindow, showMaximized() doesn't work. Why?

Tags: python, pyqt5, qwindow

It's a tiny simple code.

In this code, self.showMaximized() is not working.

And even it's so tiny, I don't know why.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

class Window(QWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QWindow.__init__(self)
        self.setTitle("title")
        self.showMaximized()
        # self.resize(400,300)
        # self.showMaximized()
        # self.showFullScreen()


app = QApplication(sys.argv)

screen = Window()
screen.show()

sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

---

Delete 'screen.show()', and then showMaximized() worked.

Comment: remove `screen.show()`. In the constructor you are maximizing the "screen" but then use show that eliminates the previous action.

Comment: If you have a new question then create a new post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either you need to use `.showMaximized()` only on newly created `Object` i.e., `screen`, but not in your constructor or only at the end of your constructor, but not twice.

**Code:**

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

class Window(QWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QWindow.__init__(self)
        self.setTitle("title")


app = QApplication(sys.argv)

screen = Window()
screen.showMaximized()

sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Wow. Even delete this code 'screen.show()' , Window class is initiating.
if then, what is the role of 'screen.show()'?

Comment: @baejusik Role of `.show()` and `.showMaximized` is similar. What your previous code doing is, first maximized the window(in a constructor) and again set default parameters(i.e., `screen.show()`)

Comment: Now I understand. I thought that 'showMaximized' is just change it's window size. And it wasn't. Thank you. ^^